# 'Unable to initialize' group in MoveIt Commander

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic, ros-industrial, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been working on developing a pick and place operation using a Fanuc M10iA, but I've run into a wall while working through [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/moveit_commander_scripting/moveit_commander_scripting_tutorial.html#using-the-moveit-commander-command-line-tool). I can get demo.launch working as expected with planning and executing paths in RViz, but the python script can never initialize a group.

From the command: `use <group_name>`

I always get the response: `Unable to initialize <group_name>`

I tried creating new groups in the srdf using different naming schemes, and I also got the same issue switching to the panda arm used in the tutorial

I did have some [issues](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/86#issuecomment-348980094) with pyassimp getting the python script to run initially, and wondering if it's a continuation of that.

Using Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311012/%27unable-to-initialize%27-group-in-moveit-commander/) by [hbirdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38995/hbirdj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying with my own Panda I can see it should work if you `use manipulator`, assuming the correct srdf is [this one](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/992e4d85d9f026749e90d08e3e509e0ce5e6f5b0/fanuc_m10ia_moveit_config/config/fanuc_m10ia.srdf#L12). At the very least, this is my own IO:

```
$ rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py
[ INFO] [1545237637.362904035]: Loading robot model 'panda'...
[ INFO] [1545237637.427494951]: Loading robot model 'panda'...

Waiting for commands. Type 'help' to get a list of known commands.

> use panda_arm
[ INFO] [1545237642.953916840]: Ready to take commands for planning group panda_arm.
OK
panda_arm>
```

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hbirdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38995/hbirdj/) on 2018-12-20**:
Yep, that's where I'm trying to reach. After inputting 'use' I get tab completion for the active groups, so it knows they're around, it just can't initialize. I'm trying to work backward through the code, but I'm not sure where to go beyond here...

**Comment by [hbirdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38995/hbirdj/) on 2018-12-20**:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/0181fc1b637f4179fad7ad233d07d88f5d789b04/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/interpreter.py#L119

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2018-12-20**:
I see, I had not understood. I don't know if there's a better way to debug the issue, but I know you could try `rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level`, setting the logging level to *Debug* for `/move_group_commander_wrappers_(...)` to see which connection isn't enstablished.

**Comment by [hbirdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/38995/hbirdj/) on 2018-12-20**:
Thanks! I had hadn't learned how to enable that logging yet. And it led me to the real issue, which is that I needed to try in a new terminal. Still unsure what the core issue was though.